# Cos'è una borsa a soffietto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Se una notte d'inverno un viaggiatore* d'Italo Calvino ho letto:

> E il 
>   mio braccio non regga una *borsa a soffietto*, gonfia e un po' 
>   logora, ma spinga una valigia quadrata di materia plastica rigida 
>   munita di piccole ruote, manovrabile con un bastone metallico 
>   cromato e pieghevole.

Cercando il vocabolo [*soffietto*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/soffietto/) nel vocabolario Treccani si trova

> Elemento (talora detto anche *mantice*) estensibile mediante piegatura a libretto, di pelle o di altro materiale flessibile, che costituisce le pareti di una camera deformabile di apparecchiature e strumenti varî o di particolari oggetti: *il s.* (o *il mantice*) *della fisarmonica; il s. degli scarponi* (da montagna), costituito da due strisce di morbida pelle cucite lungo i bordi laterali della grossa linguetta, che si piegano allacciando lo scarpone e impediscono l’infiltrazione di acqua, neve, pietrisco, e sim.; con questo sign. è soprattutto usata la locuz. *a soffietto*, con funzione di agg.: *una valigia, una borsa a s.; tasche, tasconi a s.*

Comunque, non riesco a capire cosa sia una borsa a soffietto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: La risposta di Diego è perfettamente corretta; esempio di una borsa vera e propria: http://www.e-dan.it/borsa-a-soffietto.html

Comment: ***A soffietto***:  di borse, cartelle e sim., con uno o più lati a pieghe dilatabili in modo da aumentarne la capienza: portafoglio, valigia a soffietto. http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/a-soffietto

Comment: Altro esempio di borsa a soffietto sono le vecchie borse da ufficio poi soppiantate dalle valigette 24ore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questo è un "soffietto":

[image: Soffietto]

In pratica si tratta di una giuntura estensibile, come ad esempio quella di una fisarmonica o di un mantice, fatta da un pezzo di materiale piegato a falde.

Una borsa a soffietto è semplicemente un tipo di borsa (tipicamente una femminile), la cui apertura utilizza la stessa tecnica per dilatarsi / comprimersi, tipo questa (quella grande nella foto).

[image: Borsa a soffietto]

Un altro esempio che può magari aiutarti è quello di certi tipi di portafogli.